# Do all the named colors render correctly in WinRT apps?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I was putting shapes on a canvas and noticed that some of my shapes appeared white despite being set to a different color.  When I changed the color to something different it would appear just fine.  At first I thought that it was just a fluke with one color.  After a while I noticed more.

Colors.Lavender, Colors.LavenderBlush, and Colors.Honeydew are just 3 examples.  When I set something to these colors it appears white instead.  I have tried it on 2 different screens now.  Is this just a problem in the emulator or did I go selectively color blind?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going color blind, but those colors are so subtle off-white that the difference is minimal.  Here's them next to white and if you look closely they really are different than white.
[image]

Comment: Wow!  When I see them together like that I can see the hint of color.  Thanks, for a moment there I thought perhaps I was a reincarnated dog.